# How can I download a image file to my local system using php

Tags: php

I am having multiple images, for that individual image i am having download button

```
<div>
<?php
     for($a=0;$a<5;$a++) { ?>
    <img src='image_<? echo $a;?>.jpg'/>
    <button id='dwn_<? echo $a;?>'>Download</button>
    <br>
   <? } ?>
</div>
```

If i click that download button i need to save that corresponding image to my local system.
Kindly give some solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most easiest way by using html 5

```
<div>
<?php
 for($a=0;$a<5;$a++) { ?>
 <img src='image_<? echo $a;?>.jpg'/>
 <a href='image_<? echo $a;?>.jpg' download>
     <span id='dwn_<? echo $a;?>'>Download</span >
 </a>
 <br>
<? } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way without javascript i think it would ( I edited your code, but i cant try it now)

```
<div>
  <?php
     for($a=0;$a<5;$a++) { ?>
       <img src='image_<? echo $a;?>.jpg'/>
       <form method="get" action='image_<? echo $a;?>.jpg'>
          <button id='dwn_<? echo $a;?>' type="submit">Download</button>
        </form>
       <br>
     <? } ?>
</div>
```

You can delete the id in button if you only use for download

Answer (score 0):

download.php
.........

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST) && ($_REQUEST['image_name'])){
 $filename = $_REQUEST['image_name'].'.jpg';
 // Write download code here
}
```

display_page.php
............

```
<div>
    <?php
         for($a=0;$a<5;$a++) { ?>
        <img src='image_<? echo $a;?>.jpg'/>
        <a href="download.php?image_name=<?php echo $a; ?>" >Download</a>
        <br>
       <? } ?>
    </div>
```